# Impossible to apt install on Ubuntu's bash windows 10 version

Tags: windows, shell, ubuntu, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu's unix bash on Windows 10 (this : https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6#activetab=pivot:overviewtab )

it installed well but I can't "apt install" (yes, on this version it's just "apt install")

After typing my pw I have this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-7 gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2
  libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-7-locales gcc-multilib make autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib
  gcc-7-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg
  libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp cpp-7 gcc gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-7-dev libgomp1 libisl19 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx2
  libquadmath0 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gcc-7-base amd64 7.3.0-16ubuntu3
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libisl19 amd64 0.19-1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.30-20ubuntu2~18.04
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libmpc3 amd64 1.1.0-1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 cpp-7 amd64 7.3.0-16ubuntu3
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 cpp amd64 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libcc1-0 amd64 8-20180414-1ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 8-20180414-1ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 8-20180414-1ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

(and then it continues until "Err:30")
then :

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

same when i try to update (and same for the fix missing option)

Do you have an idea of how to solve this ?  I searched on google for hours without finding anything
tryed on different connections, with antivirus OFF etc, same.

thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem occur in the past with some computers that are using an IPv6 address. is your computer using one? Also There was a discussion a while back with this same error on another stackoverflow, I can't find the link to it now. In the end it was a corporate network issue blocking apt install. Check your firewall settings and also try to disable any third part anti virus/firewall you may be running. Refer to these links as well they should help.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1720

https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/6h71ku/bash_aptget_wont_work/

Comment: is my computer using IPV6 ?
or do you mean my connection ? 
I will try this thank you !

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry, is your computer using an IPV6 address actively?